# Is it possible to "sample size weight" the effects of multiple regressors to that of a "big" regressor?

Tags: regression, meta-analysis

I know that you can't just take averages and state that it is the average effect of the big regressor (Simpson's paradox).
But I would be interested in knowing wether you could state that a positive or negative effect should at some significance level exist for a subgroup of the big regressor.

Two examples:
1: A negative effect of crime numbers (in neighbourhood A) on the amount of tourists visiting amsterdam was found in one studie and the same effect was found for neighbourhood B in another study but no significant effect was found for neighbourhood C in a third study. Could you sample size weight these and claim that with (p = the overall p value or smaller) that this effect exists for crime numbers somewhere in the entire city?

2: A positive effect on agression was found for the activity of one brain area (area A) in one study and a positive effect was found for the adjacent area (B) in two other studies. Could you sample size weight these together to say that the effect exists with (p = overall p-value or smaller) at least some where in the area A+B?

I have not yet found any literature describing just this and any referrences or general thoughts would be much appreciated!

Comment: Yes you can do that. See my answer https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/328535/stouffer-method/328583#328583